# How to integrate user tracking into dApp?

Tags: solidity, tokens, dapp-development

The problem is that it is just me who is working on the project and I have no way to use machine learning, advanced algorithms to detect fraud and prevent abuse of the system.

I was wondering if there is any solution.

Comment: This seems unrelated to solidity or tokens or blockchains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to develop your own tracking system and run it as a dApp. There is no existing solutions to this problem.